# Android Location Manager

Tags: android, google-maps, location-services

There are two providers: GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER to get our current location in Android.
Is it possible to disable location service and get the user location purely by WIFI?
I tried to disable the location service but the NETWORK_PROVIDER return false.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to disable location service and get the user location
>   purely by WIFI?

Yes it is possible by adding input to getLocastKnowsLocation as `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`

```
LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location networkLocation = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (networkLocation != null) {
            Location bestResult = networkLocation;
        }
```

Comment: What if the user turned off the location services? There are two options in location service which are gps or network. If i disable location services means both will return false. But i still can connect to internet with WIFI. So in this case, the network provider will return me false, but i still using WIFI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still get the current location of the device thru wifi. The location data available to an Android device includes the current location of the device. You can use the  [My Location layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer) and the My Location button to provide your user with their current position on the map.

One of the unique features of mobile applications is location awareness. The Location API's available in Google services facilitate adding location awareness to your app with automated location tracking, geofencing and activity recognition.

Here's a sample demo app which discuss how to get current location of the device:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MyLocationDemoActivity.java